# Magento search result layer

Tags: magento

Can you help me? When I want search some products it demage my layer. I want delete right bar. This is a image of it http://i49.tinypic.com/vopnj4.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

in app\design\frontend\your_package\your_theme\layout\catalog.xml

```
<default>
    <remove name="right" />
    .....
</default>
```

This will remove it from all catalog pages, so you may want to change it something like

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
```

What is the url path in your browser (after www.xyz.com/?)

Comment: Sorry I dont understand, but I dont want delete right block I want delete this blog only in search result layer

Comment: Add the above code to app\design\frontend\your_package\your_theme\layout\catalogsearch.xml

Comment: I dont have this file, but I found this file in folder base. It looks like this but doesnt work it. http://pastebin.com/6E8t9ptw

Comment: What version of Magento are you using?